# One request in one time unit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So. I use react library (if it matters).
Task is next - i have to get data by typing input. But problem is next - i should make request if only user finished typing.
What does it mean? I can make request once after user inputing, after 1 second for example.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called request debouncing.

You can let a library such as lodash do it for you: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce or write the function yourself.

Comment: I would like to add that debouncing and react components have a complicated relationship. Please look into examples of debouncing in React because it DOES matter